# ISP error in routing to a specific IP subnet. What can I do?

Tags: networking, router, isp

I have a brand new VPS on IP 155.xxx.xxx.xxx. I started to configure it and all of a sudden, the SSH connection shut off and I could no longer reconnect to it from my office PC. Tried later on to connect from my house (same ISP) and could not as well (no SSH, no ports 80, 443, etc. with a webserver running on the VPS box).

I can however connect to this box from other offsite servers without issue. 
I can also connect to the VPS without problem from my cellphone (other carrier than my home/office internet).

Running `tracert` / `traceroute` shows me that the IP typically gets resolved for 155.xxx.xxx.1 in 15 hops.
However, for 155.xxx.xxx.2 to 155.xxx.xxx.255, the same 15th hop sends to a 16th one that seems to block the connection. It always stops resolving at that same hop - ae0.332.lax.edge.swiftinternet.net [104.255.32.16]- as shown below:

```
C:\Users\Me>tracert 155.xxx.xxx.60

Tracing route to 155.xxx.xxx.60 over a maximum of 30 hops

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  router.localhost [192.168.2.1]
  2     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  3    13 ms    12 ms    15 ms  10.158.4.1
  4    14 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.192.55.57
  5    16 ms    15 ms    14 ms  10.192.42.225
  6    43 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.192.41.217
  7    20 ms    18 ms    15 ms  10.192.37.153
  8    17 ms    15 ms    15 ms  10.192.55.150
  9     *       18 ms     *     10.192.12.38
 10    55 ms    51 ms    54 ms  xe-0-4-0-5.r05.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.195.33]
 11    53 ms    53 ms    73 ms  ae-4.r21.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.172]
 12    82 ms    93 ms    81 ms  ae-4.r22.dllstx09.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.2.219]
 13    96 ms    99 ms    97 ms  ae-5.r22.lsanca07.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.7.69]
 14   115 ms   124 ms   114 ms  ae-1.r00.lsanca07.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.17]
 15    97 ms    99 ms   111 ms  xe-0-9-0-24.r00.lsanca07.us.ce.gin.ntt.net [129.250.207.178]
 16   222 ms   116 ms   118 ms  ae0.332.lax.edge.swiftinternet.net [104.255.32.16]
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 24     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 25     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 26     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 27     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 28     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 29     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 30     *        *        *     Request timed out.

Trace complete.
```

I've share this with the ISP for them to resolve the issue... on their clients@... email address, as directed by tech support. However, historically, they've accustomed me to poor service and 0 follow-up on these kind of issues.

So far, I identified the following fixes for this problem, but none is perfect:

- Ask for another IP in a different subnet to my VPS provider, which may not be possible at this time (request is pending)
- Connect to this IP range through VPN connection, requiring each user to setup a VPN client on their machines
- Setup office router with VPN and routing this IP range through the VPN connection, a good, transparent fix for the office but the problem would persist in users' houses, etc.
- Wait for ISP to fix the issue... might as well cancel the VPS box altogether as this won't happen any time soon.

**So, here's the question, is there something I can do to force a different route to get to that IP address that would be trouble-free to my users (meaning without having to install a VPN on their machines, etc.)?**

For example, anyone here would know what's the proper protocol for me to notify the operator of the server I consider faulty (Swiftinternet) of the issue?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Update on my status - the VPS provider did change my IP to a new one in another subnet, which solved my issue.
I am nonetheless curious to know if there is a way to correct the problem presented as I still cannot access any IP in that range...